# making a display show only if the bool is set to true in Django

Tags: python, django, boolean, admin

in admin.py

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('confirmed', 'po_number')
```

I would like to make it to where, po_number will only display if "confirmed" is set to True. How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your class:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    ... your fields ...

    def get_po_number(self):
        return self.po_number if self.confirmed else ''
    get_po_number.short_description = 'po_number'
```

And change from 'po_number' to 'get_po_number' in list_display

Answer (score 1):

The column would always display but if you want to display blank text or something when false you could try something like:

```
list_display = ('confirmed', 'get_po_number')

def get_po_number(obj):
    if obj.confirmed:
        return obj.po_number
    else:
        return 'some text'
get_po_number.short_description = 'po number'
```